# Timestamp mktime php format

Tags: php, format, timestamp, mktime

I have a php page listed below with events and I wish to order them by dates. No problem with this, but I want the date format was "15/Lug/1998" and not "15/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000". I post the code to fix this problem. Thanks in advance for your reply and help.

```
<?php

# For demo - some data that we will test with

$stuff =  <<<COURSES
02 - - [15/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.111.com">Event01</a>"
05 - - [21/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.112.com">Event02</a>"
07 - - [16/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.113.com">Event03</a>"
COURSES;

# Date in yukky format to Unix timestamp
function gdate($record) {
eregi('\[([0-9]{2})/([A-Z]{3})/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})',
    $record, $gotten);
    $yikes = 1 + (strpos("GenFebMarAprMagGiuLugAgoSetOttNovDic",
            $gotten[2]))/3; # Date "Alpha Triplet" to Month No.
     $when = mktime($gotten[4],$gotten[5],$gotten[6],
            $yikes,$gotten[1],$gotten[3]);
    return $when;
    }

function bydate($left,$right) {
    $whenone = gdate($left);
    $whentwo = gdate($right);
    if ($whenone == $whentwo) return 0;
    return (($whenone < $whentwo) ? -1 : +1);
    }

$records = explode("\n",$stuff);
sort ($records);
$result = implode("<br />",$records);
print "<hr> Normal sort</br>$result";

usort ($records,bydate);
$result = implode("<br />",$records);
print "<hr> User defined sort - by date stamp</br>$result";

?>
```

Comment: 2 solutions: 1. use date() to format it; 2. use substr() to remove /1998:00:00:00 -0000 in your timestamp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I wish enter in $stuff the date 15/Lug/1998 instead of 15/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me including the new code?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is generated through below code

```
function gdate($record) {
eregi('\[([0-9]{2})/([A-Z]{3})/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})',
    $record, $gotten);
    $yikes = 1 + (strpos("GenFebMarAprMagGiuLugAgoSetOttNovDic",
            $gotten[2]))/3; # Date "Alpha Triplet" to Month No.
     $when = mktime($gotten[4],$gotten[5],$gotten[6],
            $yikes,$gotten[1],$gotten[3]);
    return $when;
    }
```

Modify it like below:

```
function gdate($record) {
eregi('\[([0-9]{2})/([A-Z]{3})/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})',
    $record, $gotten);
    $yikes = 1 + (strpos("GenFebMarAprMagGiuLugAgoSetOttNovDic",
            $gotten[2]))/3; # Date "Alpha Triplet" to Month No.
     $time = mktime($gotten[4],$gotten[5],$gotten[6],
            $yikes,$gotten[1],$gotten[3]);
      $when = date('d/M/Y', $time);   //this is solution one, recommended
      $when = substr($time, 0, -15);  //this is solution two
    return $when;
    }
```

EDIT:
Remain your previous code and modify below part:

```
$records = explode("\n",$stuff);
```

TO:

```
$rec = str_replace(":00:00:00 -0000", "", $stuff);
$records = explode("\n",$rec);
```

Second EDIT:
Change: (Change two places)

```
$result = implode("<br />",$records);
```

To:

```
$result = implode("<br />",str_replace(":00:00:00 -0000", "", $stuff));
```

Comment: Applying your solution, dates are not sorted well.

Comment: If this affects your sorting, just apply the date() function to where you output your string. i.e. only to $result

Comment: Thanks again Godinall, but I have a poor knowledge about Php, so I ask you to write in this page the code to apply your suggestion.

Comment: where are you getting those?$stuff =  <<<COURSES
02 - - [15/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.111.com">Event01</a>"
05 - - [21/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.112.com">Event02</a>"
07 - - [16/Lug/1998:00:00:00 -0000] "<a href="http://www.113.com">Event03</a>"
COURSES;

Comment: On the web, is not mine.

Comment: See my edit. Looks you really don't know PHP, good luck is all that I can say for now.

Comment: With your two different solutions, the sort order for dates doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use my previous solution, use the one I provided under EDIT!

Comment: Before I used your first solution, then your second one (with str_replace and my previous code), but really doesn't work.

Comment: Yes only the sort order by dates. The replacement of the date is good, but I would like the date was 15/Lug/1998 and sorted well.

Comment: Okay, last try, see my second edit. It should only modify the display not the sort order.

Comment: Maybe you should have someone to help you with the project...or if you pack all your files I may have a look for you

Comment: I have only this file to fix, but without an alternative solution, I can use it.